# Marklogic- Retrieve distinct values of an XML element across documents

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

We are building a enterprise application with ML as the back end DB. One of the requirements is to find distinct values of a particular element in XML across various documents.

**Can I get the distinct entity_type using a structured query/combined query**

All the below documents are part of entity collection:

**Document 1**

```
<xml>
    <entities>
        <entity_name>Imprezza</entity_name>
        <entity_type>Car</entity_type>
        <entity_color>Red</entity_color>
    <entities>
<xml>
```

**Document 2**

```
<xml>
    <entities>
        <entity_name>Ducati</entity_name>
        <entity_type>Bike</entity_type>
        <entity_color>White</entity_color>
    <entities>
<xml>
```

**Document 3**

```
<xml>
    <entities>
        <entity_name>Lancia</entity_name>
        <entity_type>Car</entity_type>
        <entity_color>Red</entity_color>
    <entities>
<xml>
```

**Document 4**

```
<xml>
    <entities>
        <entity_name>Scania</entity_name>
        <entity_type>Truck</entity_type>
        <entity_color>Black</entity_color>
    <entities>
<xml>
```

**Requirement**: Give me all **distinct entity_type** in the collection

**Result: Car,Bike,Truck**

P.S: Need to get the result in Java layer. We currently have an API which generates MarkLogic combined queries (Structured query + options query) based on input. **Can I get the distinct entities using a structured query/combined query ??**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a lexicon (based on no spaces above)
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/lexicon

OR

You can do this with a range index on each of the values. 
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/range_index

In either case, you can retrieve the values via the values REST endpoint.
https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/values/[name]

I believe that there are java API solutions once you have your lexicons or range index in place as well.

Comment: Yes, the Java and Node.js Client APIs both expose functionality equivalent to GET /v1/values/{name}. In Java it is QueryManager.values (http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/searches#id_65191), and in Node.js it is databaseClient.values (http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/node-dev/search#id_56768).